# How to get facebook shares count with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

i 'm coding in PHP. I need to make a website with facebook feed.

I can get like and comment with : https://graph.facebook.com/<id_post>?fields=picture,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0)&access_token=;

but how can we get shares ? i've tried : [https://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}&fields=engagement&access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/?id=%7Burl%7D&fields=engagement&access_token=)<>

If i try facebook url "https://www.facebook.com"  , i have the count of shares but how with our own facebook post, "https://www.facebook.com/id/posts/post_id" dont work

i have engagement -> share_count : 0 or i have 2 shares on the post.

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/id/posts/post_id` is not how you access the actual post via API. You need to use `pageid_postid` format. And `engagement` is for Open graph objects, for posts you need to look at the `shares` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe mentions:

> `https://www.facebook.com/id/posts/post_id` is not how you access the actual post via API. You need to use `pageid_postid` format. And `engagement` is for Open graph objects, for posts you need to look at the `shares` field.

with ?fields=shares it's work